# How can I tell if r-base-dev is installed?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu.  R is definitely installed - I can launch it and I can see its folder in bin/.

How can I tell if `r-base-dev` is installed?

Will installing `r-base-dev` fix the issues I'm having with missing system packages with I try to `install.packages("tidyverse")`?

Many thanks!

Comment: `dpkg -l r-base-dev` tells you whether it's installed. As to whether installing it will fix installation errors you are seeing from attempting to install ‘tidyverse’, the error message should *usually* tell you which system dependencies need to be installed.

Comment: there are also various ways to install package binaries on ubuntu which can take care of dependencies : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383251/how-to-install-r-package-binaries-on-linux-just-like-on-windows  (and cran link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html)