# Installing R packages on WSL2 takes long time

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently changing my work environment from Rstudio to VScode on WSL2. I notice that every R package I install takes considerably more time than what I am used to with Rstudio on Windows 11. Is this normal?

Comment: You haven’t provided a whole lot of details about what exactly is going on. So you are basically switching from running R on the windows OS to Linux? Packages have to be compiles for different operating systems. Most likely when you run on windows you are using pre-compiled packages from the CRAN mirror. When you run on Linux, there are way more different ways that systems are configured so it usually default to compiling packages locally from source. But you should have to install the package only once.

Comment: [How to install R package binaries on Linux just like on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59383251/646761)

Comment: https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/ provides binary packages for many distros of linux

Comment: @r2evans Please post it as an answer so I can make it best answer.

Comment: This is similar enough to others, I'll provide a dupe link. Glad it worked for you!